# Java android replece HTTPClient to AsyncHttpClient

Tags: java, android

In my application I use a HTTPClient but is a depreceted and I want to repleace this to AsyncHttpClient. This is my code which I use to HttpCLient and it works corretly :

```
HttpClient httpclient = HttpClientUtil.getHttpClient(context);
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(Util.getServerUrl(context)
                + "/GetData");
        String login_xml = QueryGenerator.getDataRequest(version, power, lon,
                lat, radius, Util.getLastStamp(context));

        ArrayList<NameValuePair> namevaluepairs = new ArrayList<>(2);
        namevaluepairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("token", String
                .valueOf(E_Gps.TOKEN)));
        namevaluepairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("xml", login_xml));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(namevaluepairs, HTTP.UTF_8));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        InputStream responseInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(response
                .getEntity().getContent());
```

And this is what I did in AsyncHttpClient but it doesn't work corretly :

```
AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
String url = Util.getServerUrl(context) + "/GetData";
ContentValues values=new ContentValues();
values.put("token", String.valueOf(E_Gps.TOKEN));
values.put("xml", login_xml);
StringEntity entity = null;
try {
    entity = new StringEntity(values.toString());
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
entity.setContentType(new BasicHeader("Content-Type","application/xml"));

client.post(context,url,entity, "application/xml", new AsyncHttpResponseHandler(Looper.getMainLooper()) {

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
        Log.e("success_noti", new String(responseBody) + "");

    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {
        Log.e("success_noti", new String(responseBody) + "");
        Log.e("Status " , statusCode + " ");
    }

});
```

Comment: Well what is not correct exactly?

Comment: @greenapps a response from server is 400 Bad Request

Comment: "application/xml" is not ok. Use form url encoded instead. Google for the right description.

Answer (score 0):

[android-async-http post request with body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35644560/android-async-http-post-request-with-body/35644819#35644819)

[Java android AsyncHttpClient how set header 'Accept' an 'application / xml' or 'application / json'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43884542/java-android-asynchttpclient-how-set-header-accept-an-application-xml-or/43885184#43885184)

have a look & I think you have to use RequestParams inplace of Content values

Comment: I replece a ContentValues to RequestParams but it doesn't work

Comment: Please have a look on the links given in answer